# modifying BST style & calling citation

Tags: bibtex

I have two problems I am grappling with.

The first involves editing the BST file to suit my needs. I want something that looks like this:
[image]

I was able to get the line break between the note and the URL by inserting `\par` in the original bib entry (e.g. `note={\par blah blah blah}`) but surely there is an easier, more elegant way? Also, I would like a line break after the article title.
I have made various modifications to:

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
    format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    {
      journal
      "journal" bibinfo.check
      emphasize
      "journal" output.check
      format.date "year" output.check
      date.block
      format.vol.num.pages output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  format.issn output
  new.block
  format.url output 
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
```

Without any success. Where or how can I modify the above to insert a line break. Or should be editing:

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { "t" change.case$ }
  if$
  "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      bolden
    }
  if$
}
```

and

```
FUNCTION {format.note}
{
 note empty$
    {  "" }
    { note #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "{" =
        'skip$
        { output.state mid.sentence =
          { "l" }
          { "u" }
       if$
        change.case$
        }
      if$
      note #2 global.max$ substring$ * "note" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
} ?
```

The other issue is the date. I don't want a period after the year, I just want a space. (I swore this is what I instructed makebst...) In the past I have editted the date field to replace a comma with a period but I can't see anything about periods and commas in the date function:

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
{
  month "month" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$
  year  "year"  bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
    { swap$ 'skip$
        { "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$ }
      if$
      *
    }
    { swap$ 'skip$
        {
          swap$
          " " * swap$
        }
      if$
      *
    }
  if$
  duplicate$ empty$
    'skip$
    {
      before.all 'output.state :=
    " " swap$ *
    }
  if$
}
```

The second question is more daring.
I want PDFLaTeX to call the citation (as defined in the BST file) in the body of the document as if it were inputting a .tex file instead of a citation. So, instead of the text showing (for example) Akbarzadeh et al 2016 it will load the entire entry as I have defined it. I don't want something that looks like a bibliography but will look more like this:

[image]

Any ideas how to accomplish this? I am hoping there is a package somewhere that does just this.

I'm not sure what type of minimal example is needed... Let me know what you think you need to help solve this.

Thanks

Comment: The best option for your requests would be to switch to `biblatex`. You can program the output of your bibliography in latex. The second requests would be just a by-product of the switch and all you need is to call `\fullcite{key}`.

Comment: Thank you, Guido. I will have a look at BibLaTeX and see if I can figure it out. Thanks also for tidying up my post. I couldn't figure out how to insert the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out BibLaTeX (it doesn't seem to run in TeXWorks or there was a problem with the Package or something...) but I found a solution here: https://tug.org/pracjourn/2008-1/calleecharan/

Minimal examples:
The Tex File

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[twoside,inner=25.4mm,tmargin=25.4mm,nohead,bmargin=25.4mm,textwidth=159.2mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\nocite{begcla1}

\nocite{art2}

\nocite{endcla1}

\nocite{art1}

\nocite{endcla2}

%\nocite{Elem2}

\bibliographystyle{datastyle}
\bibliography{dataset}

\end{document}
```

The bib file:

```
@CREATESECTION{begcla1,
heading={Section 1} 
}

@style1{art1,
title = { My dog eats cats},
author = {Katz, JP},
journal = { Cat cuisine},
volume = {1},
pages = {3--5},
year = {2016},
url = {\url{http://www.cateaters.com}},
note = {I found this article delicious.}
}

@ENDSECTION{endcla1
}

@CREATESECTION{begcla2,
heading={Section 2} 
}

@style1{art2,
title = { My cat eats dogs},
author = {Dags, JP},
journal = { Dog cuisine},
volume = {1},
pages = {3--5},
year = {2016},
url = {\url{http://www.dogeaters.com}},
note = {It made me gag.}
}

@ENDSECTION{endcla2
}
```

the bst file:

```
Entry
{
title
heading
author
journal
volume
pages
year
url
note
} {} {}

FUNCTION{print}
{
    cite$ pop$
}

FUNCTION {bolden}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\fontfamily{lmss}\bfseries\selectfont\large " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.heading}
{ heading bolden
}

FUNCTION{createsection}
{
"\vspace{0.5cm}" write$
newline$ newline$ write$
newline$ newline$ write$
 write$ newline$ print format.heading write$ newline$  write$
newline$ newline$ write$
newline$ newline$ write$
"\vspace{0.25cm}" write$
}

FUNCTION{Style1}{
"{\fontfamily{lmss}\bfseries\selectfont " write$ print title write$ "}"     write$%
print write$ ". " write$ newline$ newline$
print write$ author write$%
print write$ ". " write$%
print "{\em " write$ print journal write$ "}" write$%
print write$ ", " write$%
print volume  write$%
print write$ ":" write$%
print pages  write$%
print write$ ", " write$%
print write$ year write$%
print write$ "." write$ newline$ newline$
print write$ url  write$ newline$ newline$
print write$ ``{\normalsize `` write$ print note write$ ``}'' write$     newline$ newline$
}

FUNCTION{fin}
{newline$
}

Read

ITERATE{call.type$}

EXECUTE{fin}
```

I would like to find a way to include the `\url` formatting in the BST instead of the bib file but haven't figured out how to. This isn't as elegant a solution as I had hoped but it will do a job.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to tidy the code it would be much appreciated. I don't really know what I'm doing...